# Setting Jersey to allow caching?

Tags: rest, jersey, resteasy

I have the following returned from a Jersey @GET method. It works, fine but always includes the No-cache header. I'd like to allow the client to cache this data since it rarely changes.

```
ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(c);
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setMaxAge(60);
    cc.setNoCache(false);
    return rb.cacheControl(cc).build();
```

The response is always:

```
 Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Pragma No-cache
 Cache-Control  no-cache, no-transform, max-age=60
 Expires    Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
 Content-Type   application/xml
 Content-Length 291
 Date   Tue, 16 Feb 2010 01:54:02 GMT
```

That am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by having BASIC auth turned on.

Specifying this in the context will correct the issue:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"
       disableProxyCaching="false" />
```

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay.

Which container are you using? Make sure cache is not disabled on it. Also verify downstream response handlers or filters aren't setting the no-cache directive.

Comment: Using Tomcat6. I'll take a look at that, thanks! I'm going crazy over here!

Comment: Also using Spring, not sure if that matters. I don't see anything in container which would set this. Still looking though.

Comment: Cache headers can be set in Spring as well. I think the "no-cache" usually doesn't get set by default. Try hitting a static resource to rule out Tomcat first. Then depending on how complex your app is, peel it one layer at a time, e.g. 1) wire up a plain servlet or jsp in Spring and check the cache-control header; 2) temporarily disable all filters; etc.

Comment: Turns out that I think it is having something to do with BasicAuth.. I need dig in more.